# Find the derivative of an integral with an integral as a boundary

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I was given the task to find the derivative of the following function:

$$F(x)=\int_0^ {g(x)}{\dfrac{1}{1+\sin^2(x)}dx}$$

With $$g(x) = \int_0^ {x^2}{\dfrac{1}{1+\sin^2(x)}dx}$$

My attempt was to apply the principal of integral calculations so that I know 
$F(x)$ without any integral signs. Then, I could find the derivative of that function. Sadly I am totally stuck at integrating

$$\int{\dfrac{1}{1+\sin^2(x)}dx}$$

Could someone help me with this? 
Also it would be great if someone could tell me if there is an easier way of integrating an expression like given above because “finding the derivative of an integral” sounds way more easy.

Greetings, Finn

Comment: You familiar with Leibniz Rule?

Comment: No, could that be used here?

Comment: Yes, @Finn See [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: I will try to understand it. Give me a minute. But thank you in advance!

Comment: Wow that’s good... Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Leibniz' rule of [differentiating under the integral sign](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule&ved=0ahUKEwiJkOPQ2uvYAhUGbo8KHT6aByAQmhMIPzAC&usg=AOvVaw0TLcFrqPCjE07SW-pbnpxJ) to get: $$f'(x) =\frac1{1+\sin^2 g(x) } g'(x) $$ with $$g'(x) = \frac1{1+\sin^2 x^2}(2x)$$

Comment: You just beat me by 15 seconds.